# How to change text depending on the country

Tags: localization

a few texts fields on the site need to be different in one specific country

on (Category & Custom home page)

Eg:

Class 1 (India)
Grade 1 (UK)
First Grade (US)

Any idea on how I could do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several plugins out there that help you to translate your site content. Though you could have googled that by yourself easily, look here to get a brief overview:
https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/top-6-translation-plugins-for-your-wordpress-site/

WPML is a very powerful translation plugin (not free), in your case qTranslate should be good enough and is easier to implement than WPML I guess.